# How to pass value from one response to the other Request in Jmeter

Tags: web-services, rest, jmeter

I am trying to test RESTfull WS using jmeter, in which I want to use the value from one xml response to another xml request.
So any One please help me like how can i do that as I am new to jmeter.

Thanks in advance.

---

Code for Pre-Processor added from below comments:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.WebServiceSampler;

WebServiceSampler wsSampler = (WebServiceSampler) sampler;
String SessionToken = wsSampler.getXmlData().replaceFirst("#sessionToken#", vars.get("sessionToken"));
wsSampler.setXmlData(SessionToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use any post-processor: [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - more preferably for your case, - or even [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as the most powerful.
Post-processor added as child sampler to the sampler which response you want process will extract value into the variable which one you can use than in the next request.

Comment: Alies thanks for the Reply, i used xpath Extracter and then  BeanShell PreProcessor to set the value of the Session token from the Response to the second Request but i am not getting the proper response.This is the code i am using........................................................

Comment: import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.WebServiceSampler;
WebServiceSampler wsSampler = (WebServiceSampler) sampler;
String SessionToken = wsSampler.getXmlData().replaceFirst("#sessionToken#", vars.get("sessionToken"));
wsSampler.setXmlData(SessionToken);                                         ............... but i am not able to pass the value of the Session to the xml file, can you help me like how to do this with some Example of some sample example you can provide will be very helpfull